# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework Core how to create a separate table for each data subset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I currently have a class called `SingleSymbolData` that contains all of the associated weekly stock data.

```
public class SingleSymbolData
{ 
    [Key]
    public int SingleSymbolKey { get; set; }

    public string SymbolName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WeeklyStockData> WeeklyStockDataCollection { get; set; } = new List<WeeklyStockData>();
}
```

The weekly stock data looks like this:

```
public class WeeklyStockData
{
    public WeeklyStockData()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int StockDataID { get; set; }

    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public float Volume { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that all of the weekly stock data is being added to a single table called `WeeklyStockData`. Meanwhile I have another table called `SingleSymbolData` which contains a foreign key.

The problem is that the single `WeeklyStockData` table is starting to get very large, and will just get larger with the more weekly stock data I add.

I was wondering if there was some way I could create a table for each subset of weekly stock data so that the foreign key of the `SingleSymbolData` table would point to that separate table.

Here is what my db set stuff looks like:

```
public DbSet<SingleSymbolData> StockSymbols { get; set; }
public DbSet<WeeklyStockData> WeeklyStockData { get; set; }
```

I'm hoping this would be possible for performance reasons since queries are just getting slower on the individual table. Let me know if I'm going down the wrong path here. I'm open to other solutions as well, or changing my current entity setup. Please let me know if I should add more of my code or more information. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why split the same data between multiple tables? Tables are supposed to have data, that's totally fine. Reading the same data set from multiple tables will become a nightmare. If the queries are getting slow due to the amount of data you probably need better indexing and/or better queries.

Comment: I'm fairly new to databases so I didn't realize indexing was a thing. That sounds perfect, thanks for your help.